# selecting video from local iphone like picker?

Tags: iphone

How can I select the video from photo folder or video folder and its file name which must be in iphone locally through programming?

Is there any way to check the video is already in iPhone locally, when i get file name of that
video from the internet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick a video from the library, or let the user record a video, use `UIImagePickerController` with the appropriate media types.

I don't think you'll be able to get its file name, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you might be looking for the [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).